# Return inside or outside the using statement?

Tags: c#, return, using-statement

Should I do the `return` inside or outside the `using`statement?

```
public IEnumerable<Foo> GetData()
{
    using (var db = new DbContext())
    {
        return db.Foo().ToList();
    }
}
```

or

```
public IEnumerable<Foo> GetData()
{
    IEnumerable<Foo> foo;

    using (var db = new DbContext())
    {
        foo = db.Foo().ToList();
    }

    return foo;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't matter: the IL is identical. First code fragment is more readble though.

Comment: You don't get any errors, right? And if you have question, then [`MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) should normally be the first to check (it doesn't explain `return`, but `finally`). But having all those `C#` books writers at your disposal is .. handy!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not matter. Effectively, the same thing is going to happen - namely, the data that you are about to return will be saved in a temporary for the duration of calling the `Dispose()` method on the `db` object.

Different shops prefer different coding standards. For example, some shops insist on not having returns except on the last line; in this case, the second alternative needs to be used. I prefer the first snippet, because it conveys the same meaning with fewer variables, and less code overall.

Answer (score 7):

Either is fine. There's no particular technical reason to put it outside, so do whatever fits your style best. Returning from within the `using` statement is akin to returning from within a `try` block that has a `finally` attached to it; either way, the `finally` block (explicit, or implicit in the case of `using`) is executed.